# VBA thinks Integer is Object

Tags: vba, excel

This code return Error 91 for line set value of the NotCopySheet variable. When I only keep the code to the MsgBox line, VBA run fine.
I have a named range "NotCopy" in the sheet I run.
I don't have much VBA experience. This is a code I found to do what I need. I will use the NotCopySheet variable to stop copying/delete a few first sheets.

```
Sub CopyWorkbookValue()

Dim Output As Workbook, Source As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim FileName As String
Dim OriginalName As String
Dim firstCell
Dim NotCopySheet As Integer

OriginalName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
NotCopySheet = ActiveSheet.Range("NotCopy").Cells(1, 1).Value
MsgBox "The number of sheet ignore is " & NotCopySheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook
Set Output = Workbooks.Add
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim i As Integer

For Each sh In Source.Worksheets

    Dim newSheet As Worksheet

    ' select all used cells in the source sheet:
    sh.Activate
    sh.UsedRange.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy

    ' create new destination sheet:
    Set newSheet = Output.Worksheets.Add(after:=Output.Worksheets(Output.Worksheets.Count))
    newSheet.Name = sh.Name

    ' make sure the destination sheet is selected with the right cell:
    newSheet.Activate
    firstCell = sh.UsedRange.Cells(1, 1).Address
    newSheet.Range(firstCell).Select

    ' paste the values:
    Range(firstCell).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    Range(firstCell).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Range(firstCell).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

Next

' delete the sheets that were originally there
While Output.Sheets.Count > Source.Worksheets.Count
  Output.Sheets(1).Delete
Wend

FileName = "C:\Dropbox\0 EPAS Export\ValueOnly_" & OriginalName
Output.SaveAs FileName
'Output.Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: ¿You get `Error 91` on line `NotCopySheet = ActiveSheet.Range("NotCopy").Cells(1, 1).Value`? What is the value of `ActiveSheet.Range("NotCopy").Cells(1, 1).Value`? Are you sure the range is names `NotCopy`?

Comment: I get errors where you try to name a sheet as an existing sheet name and also with  Range(firstCell).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths If the range is named correctly I get no errors with the aforementioned line.

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns: 1) Yes, that the line. 2) The value is 2 (=SHEET()). 3) I checked for the named range many times.

Comment: If the value is `2 (=SHEET()). 3)`, that's a text, and you are trying to store it in a numeric variable. That may cause the error.

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns: It's still the same error when I change the cell function to `=VALUE(SHEET())`. Also, it appear clearly in excel that's a number, not a text

Comment: I understood that the value was `2 (=SHEET()). 3)`, not a formula. So I ask again, what value returns that formula?

Comment: The function in that cell is `=SHEET()`. The value that the function return is 2. The number displayed in the cell/range is 2. The range `NotCopy` has only 1 cell.

Comment: Make sure when you execute the code that the ActiveSheet is the sheet that contains your named range. Could be that? Because If I replicate your code, I get errors only if the named range is wrong, as @QHarr.

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns: I make very certain that I run the code from the sheet that contain the Range, because exactly of that ActiveSheet. How can I change it into the named range in active workbook?

Comment: In Formulas > Name Manager, is the `Scope` of `NotCopy` listed as Workbook, or Sheet2?

Comment: @CLR: The `Scope` of `NotCopy` is Workbook.

Comment: I'm slightly concerned by *"When I only keep the code to the MsgBox line, VBA run fine"* - which suggests that something after the MsgBox line is causing the entire Sub to run again.. This Sub isn't called by an event is it?

Comment: @CLR: That's the entire code. I don't believe that it has anything that go back to beginning.

Comment: You're missing to mention something here about your specific case. Do a test yourself: close all excels. Create a new workbook. Name a cell "NotCopy", enter =Sheet() in it and try to assign it to an int variable in VBA. Works on my end. I'm fairly sure that there is something not mentioned here. Perhaps consider desensitizing your workbook and upload it somewhere and we'll have a look.

Comment: Why do you have the line `NotCopySheet = ActiveSheet.Range("NotCopy").Cells(1, 1).Value` in your code? You don't use the variable `NotCopySHeet` anywhere in your code, except in a MsgBox. OPs the use code from internet sources and don't know what the code is doing usually put useless code into their macros. OPs need to start with basic code and stay away from advanced code until they are more experienced. Please see my answer to show you a basic way to copy the worksheets in a workbook and paste to a new workbook.

Comment: @GMalc:  **"I will use the NotCopySheet variable to stop copying/delete a few first sheets."** I already state it in my question.

Comment: From MicroSoft [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/refer-to-named-ranges); A WorkSHEET Specific Named Range refers to a range in a specific worksheet, and it is not global to all worksheets within a workbook. If you have the wrong worksheet active, the Range Name is invalid and you will get the error. Please read the Microsoft link to find out how to properly use it from another worksheet.

Comment: The code I put in a add-in because I want this code to be used in many different files. Does that make a different? When I check for the file name, it's still the workbook that's supposed to be copied which has the named range. I check it by simply put a Message box telling me the name of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this code is run from an add-in, I think the `ActiveSheet` may have difficulty implementing. So I changed the code slightly to make sure that the code would refer the operating workbook. Now it works fine.

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = ActiveWorkbook.Names("NotCopy").RefersToRange
NotCopySheet = r.Cells(1, 1).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code, it can be accomplished in one line of code.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Dropbox\0 EPAS Export\ValueOnly_" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ".xlsx"
```

or better

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Dropbox\0 EPAS Export\ValueOnly_" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ".xlsx"
```

Update: `ThisWorkbook.Name` refers to the workbook that has the macro. From what i understood from your code you were trying to copy all the worksheets, from the `ActiveWorkbook`. Using `ActiveWorkbook` could have undesirable results, if another workbook is active when you run your macro. The `ValueOne & workbook.name` is the new workbook naming convention you were going to use. You also commented earlier that you wanted to remove a worksheet, you can accomplish that by adding code to your macro or just opening the new workbook and deleting the worksheet you want to get ride of.

Comment: I put the code in an add-in because I want to use this functionality excel-wise not just for a specific file. `ThisWorkBook.Name` would refer to the new workbook created as destination of copying.

Comment: I removed the sheets that not needed copying simply by not copying it. I just put this before the copying code.
`If sh.Index <= NotCopySheet Then
    Else`

Comment: @TamLe I figured you would either ask how to accomplish that or find the answer yourself, good job.

Comment: Thank you. I tried. That doesn't change the fact that I am still a very beginner at VBA. Still have a lot to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely being caused by the "ActiveSheet" in NotCopySheet = ActiveSheet.Range("NotCopy").Cells(1, 1).Value.  If the ActiveSheet is not the sheet which has the named range "NotCopy", it will cause problems.  Having said that, your code is far more complicated than it needs to be.  All you're trying to do is convert all the formulas to values and then save the file under a new name.

```
   Sub CopyWorkbookValue()
    Dim NotCopySheet As Integer
    On Error GoTo ErrorExit
        NotCopySheet = Range("NotCopy").Cells(1, 1).Value
        MsgBox "The number of sheet ignore is " & NotCopySheet
       For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            sh.UsedRange.Copy
            sh.UsedRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
       Next sh
       ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Dropbox\0 EPAS Export\ValueOnly_" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ".xlsx"
     Exit Sub
ErrorExit:
     MsgBox "Error text here."
    End Sub
```

Looking at your code, it looks like you're over-relying on the macro recorder to generate your code.  While the macro recorder is useful, it also generates lot of unneeded code. Stop and think about what exactly it that you want to do and then use the macro recorder to generate the code snippets that will do what you want.  Look at the code the macro recorder generates and figure what exactly each line is really doing and if you really need to include it in your code.

Comment: Yes.  Also I added some error handling to the code, so that if a user deletes the "NotCopy" named range, you can handle it and display the appropriate message.

Comment: How do I make it if there is no `NotCopy` range, the value of `NotCopySheet` become zero?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611900/test-if-range-exists-in-vba